# Lazy transition animations react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

Hi I am using React to render some lists. I receive data via xhr and display these. Part of the data is displaying a progress bar of some kind. 
Thats done by a div element, that gets an inline width style.

In css changes to the width will cause these changes to be animated. However since that's rendered simultenously alongside the rest of the DOM, thats not animated on first render. As a workaround I do use a timeout.

I wonder if I could do better in this matter, since I consider timeouts not being a good practice. I'd rather prefer using any kind of event triggered behavior. Sth. like "After render" or similar things. Any thoughts?

```
class Container extends React.Component {

componentDidMount() {

    let maxPts = 0;
    const persons = fetchPersons();

    persons.forEach(function (person) {
        maxPts = Math.max(maxPts, person.Pts || 0);
    });

    this.setState({
        data: athletes,
        dataAccepted: true
    });

    // TODO: Is that a good practice? Causes the width to be set later on to allow a transition
    window.setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
            max: maxPts
        });
    }, 250);
}

render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Presenter max={this.state.max} persons={this.state.data}/>
        </View>
    );
}
```

}

Comment: You can use an other argument in [setState](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

"The second parameter is an optional callback function that will be executed once setState is completed and the component is re-rendered."

Comment: Does't this problem disappear if u will use real asyc fetching of persons ?

Comment: @ Axnyff thanks for that hint. Thought that might work. I also tried componentDidUpdate. However since the browser still not have rendered it completely at that point in time, the update on the maxPts will still change the initial state, not an update state.

Comment: @ disstruct sadly not, since without these persons, no points > no dom for these persons will exist. Therefore also no update on styles.